# Know which partitions are primary and which logical

Tags: linux, partition

I have Windows and Ubuntu installed on the same laptop. How can I know which partitions are logical or primary using the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total data storage space of a PC HDD can contain at most four *primary* partitions, or alternatively three *primary* partitions and an *extended* partition.

[image]

Here is an example showing both: `/proc/partitions/` and `fdisk` and their corresponding. As you can see at the picture, `fisk` tells it by `Extended` whereas `/proc/partitions/` provides a code, a number: 1-4 for primary and extended partitions  and 5+ for logical partitions. It is an Extended partition marked with red by me to highlight that logical partitions start with number 5 right after the Extended Partition.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're using legacy PC partitions (UEFI and other partition schemes have no notion of “primary partition” vs “logical partition”), the partition type can be determined from the number.

- Partitions numbered 1 through 4 are primary or extended. An extended partition is one that acts as a container for logical partitions, it cannot contain anything else such as a filesystem.
- Partitions numbered 5 and above are logical partitions.

You can see the list of available partitions with `cat /proc/partitions`. You can view a disk's partition table with the `fdisk` command, e.g. `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.